# How to append time interval in datetime format to string?

Tags: python, string, datetime

I want to create a file path in the below format using python

```
Input\tmp +datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 11, 19, 22, 3)
Expect output: \tmp\20190811T192203
```

Comment: Could you explain the components of the input? It appears `2019` is the year, and `8` is the month, but I don't know where you got the `11` from and  what the `19`, `22`, and `3` were used for. I would guess `19` is for the hour and `22` for the minute, but the `3` is ambiguous.

Comment: @Paul That was 11 in the Input and 3 is seconds, I'll edit it and yes you are correct.

Comment: check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) on `strftime`

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 5, 19, 22, 3)
output = "\\tmp\{}".format(dt.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S"))

print(output)
```

output

```
\tmp\20190805T192203
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 11, 19, 22, 3)
output = "\\tmp\\" + date.strftime("%Y%m%d") + "T" + date.strftime("%H%M%S")
```

Outputs:

```
\tmp\20190811T192203
```

Comment: why two calls to strftime? - see my comment on @BryanWoo's answer.

Comment: I had to separate for the `T` I'm not that advanced at Python. It looks like @Bryan knows how to use regular expressions.

Comment: [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are something else ;-) here, you need a formatting directive for strftime.